# How do you split a string into lists unless it is inside quotation marks ("") in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

I'm reading an input file of several lines. Each line has the following format:

```
Greeting "hello"
Greeting " Good morning"
Sit
Smile
Question "How are you?"
```

My current can read each line into a string list. Then I process it using this function which is supposed to break it into a string list list:

```
let rec process (l : string list) (acc : string list list) : string list list = 
  match l with
  | [] -> acc
  | hd :: tl -> String.split_on_char ' ' hd :: (process tl acc)
```

Which, unfortunately, does not work, since it also splits spaces inside quotation marks. Anyone think of a the right way to do this, possibly using map or fold_left, etc?  This would be my expected output:

```
[["Greeting"; "/"hello/""];[Greeting; "/" Good morning"];["Sit"]]
```

and so on. Thank you!

Comment: You're asking for a real (though very basic) lexical analysis, not just a simple split operation. Is this for a school assignment? If so, you should probably try writing your own little scanner. OCaml has lexical analysis tools, but they might be overkill for this simple problem. (Or they might be exactly what you should use.)

Comment: No, this is not for a school assignment. I simplified my problem to make it more generalized. What do you mean by "scanner?" I thought about getting the index of the first occurrence of a ' ' then splitting, from - to it but I thought there must be a simpler way somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be visualized with a state machine. You have 2 main states: looking for ' ' and looking for '"'. Processing strings is ugly and you can't pattern match it. So first thing I did is turn the string into a char list. Implementing the two states then becomes simple:

```
let split s =
  let rec split_space acc word = function
  | [] -> List.rev (List.rev word::acc)
  | ' '::xs -> split_space (List.rev word::acc) [] xs
  | '"'::xs -> find_quote acc ('"'::word) xs
  | x::xs -> split_space acc (x::word) xs
  and find_quote acc word = function
  | [] -> List.rev (List.rev word::acc)
  | '"'::xs -> split_space acc ('"'::word) xs
  | x::xs -> find_quote acc (x::word) xs
  in
  split_space [] [] s
;;

# split ['a';'b';' ';'"';'c';' ';'d';'"';' ';'e'];;
- : char list list = [['a'; 'b']; ['"'; 'c'; ' '; 'd'; '"']; ['e']]
```

Now if you want to do it with strings that's left to you. The Idea would be the same. Or you can just turn the char list list into a string list at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You want a real (but very simple) lexical analysis. IMHO this is beyond what you can do with simple string splitting.

A scanner takes a stream of characters and returns the next token it sees. You can make a string into a stream by having an index that traverses the string.

Here is a scanner that is roughly what you would want:

```
let rec scan s offset =
    let slen = String.length s in
    if offset >= slen then
        None
    else if s.[offset] = ' ' then
        scan s (offset + 1)
    else if s.[offset] = '"' then
        let rec qlook loff =
            if loff >= slen then
                (* Unterminated quotation *)
                let tok = String.sub s offset (slen - offset) in
                Some (tok, slen)
            else if s.[loff] = '"' then
                let tok = String.sub s offset (loff - offset + 1) in
                Some (tok, loff + 1)
            else qlook (loff + 1)
        in
        qlook (offset + 1)
    else
        let rec wlook loff =
            if loff >= slen then
                let tok = String.sub s offset (slen - offset) in
                Some (tok, slen)
            else if s.[loff] = ' ' || s.[loff] = '"' then
                let tok = String.sub s offset (loff - offset) in
                Some (tok, loff)
            else
                wlook (loff + 1)
        in
        wlook (offset + 1)
```

It handles a few cases that you didn't specify: what to do if there is an unclosed quotation. What to do with something like `abc"def ghi"`.

The scanner returns `None` at the end of the string, or `Some (token, offset)`, i.e., the next token and the offset to continue scanning.

A recursive function to break up a string would look something like this:

```
let split s =
    let rec isplit accum offset =
        match scan s offset with
        | None -> List.rev accum
        | Some (tok, offset') -> isplit (tok :: accum) offset'
    in
    isplit [] 0
```